# Ejecutar una consulta SQL segun los select que se hayan seleccionado

Tags: php, mysql, validación

les cuento que actualmente estoy trabajando en un sistema de reportes de solicitudes, el cual ya logré filtrar las consultas por año,mes y semestre.

[image: Pagina que permite seleccionar filtro]

Actualmente estoy logrando filtrar por Año y Mes de forma exitosa, estos filtro se aplican mediante controles "select" que al hacer click en enviar son rescatados por otra pagina .php que se llama "ejemploPost.php", donde efectivamente estoy rescatando mediante $_POST los valores seleccionados.
Mi problema es que cuando ingreso un año pero no ingreso un mes, no me muestra nada, esto se debe a que la consulta SQL es la siguiente :

```
                $con_sol="SELECT * FROM detalle_sal where YEAR(fec_ini_s) ='$anio_selec' and MONTH(fec_ini_s) ='$mes_selec' Order by (fec_ini_s) ASC";  
                $exeSol=mysql_query($con_sol);
             ?>
```

Este es el código que rescata los valores seleccionados, este codigo está contenido en un archivo .php que se ejecuta cuando se clickea el submit en la primera página(foto), la cual esta mostrando todos los registros existentes.

```
        <?php
   $anio_selec = $_POST['selector_anio'];
   $mes_selec = $_POST['selector_mes'];
   $sem_selec = $_POST['selector_sem'];

   echo $anio_selec;
   echo $mes_selec;
   echo $sem_selec;
?>
```

Aquí viene mi inquietud, como puedo hacer que solo se ejecute una consulta especifica para un select especifico, me explico, como puedo hacer que al seleccionar un año y no seleccionar mes, se muestre solo el año ? que las consultas funcionen por si solas ?

Sería de gran ayuda si alguien podiera orientarme con la estructura de algún ciclo que me permita validar que no hayan campos vacíos en la selección.

Saludos amigos!

Comment: ¿Por qué no usas un IF para llamar una consulta u otra? Lo mejor sería hacerlo con procedimientos almacenados (stored procedures). Te recomiendo también que no utilices funciones en tus columnas en la clausula WHERE porque pueden impedir que se utilicen índices. Usa rangos de fechas en su lugar.

Comment: Por favor, modifica la pregunta e incorpora la estructura de las tablas en SQL con algún registro para las pruebas (phpMyAdmin,Exportar) y así podamos montar un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Indica exactamente el resultado quieres obtener para esos datos de ejemplo e incorpora el código de tus intentos. Aquí se explica mucho mejor [ask]. Bienvendo a [so]

Comment: ¿Qué tal vas con ese proyecto? ¿Te animas a pasarnos el dataset para que podamos ayudarte?